# issue with place adMob below web view in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, admob

For the last five days I am trying to place google admob bellow the webView. What thing I am missing please help. In case if the ad displays it occupies whole window and hides everything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:visibility="visible">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_weight="0.97" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

And Java code goes:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: just use Adview tag below the WebView tag in xml .........

Comment: @SushilKumar it did not work. Please help

Comment: change orientation to the vertical and add gravity in adview is 0.03

Comment: In case if the add displays it hides the webview...

Comment: please have look on my answer ...........if any problem feel free to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a RelativeLayout, like this

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/myId"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_weight="0.97" />

</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/myId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this xml instead of your xml.....

there is 6 to 7 changes in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_weight="0.90" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
            android:visibility="visible">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

enjoy coding..........

Comment: Thank you from 2020